# How to get record count per day in last week without today's data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to make a report shows and counts yesterday,2 days ago,3 days ago....7 days's ago data.
When it counts total data, includes today's data. I don't want that.

I want to count Day1(yesterday),day2(2 days ago) + day3 + day4 +day5 + day6 + day7

`COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 THEN 1 END) AS "Day1",                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-2 THEN 1 END) AS "Day2",                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-3 THEN 1 END) AS "Day3",                                 COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4 THEN 1 END) AS "Day4",                                  COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-5 THEN 1 END) AS "Day5",                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-6 THEN 1 END) AS "Day6",                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(Eventtime) =TRUNC(SYSDATE)-7 THEN 1 END) AS "Day7",                                    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL`

I tried this but it still counts today's data

`and eventtime <sysdate`

Any sql query solution?

Comment: Your code is clearly Oracle code, so I removed the SQL Server tag.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why `to_char(...) = sysdate`?

Comment: @astentx My guess is that they are using it with their default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to emulate the behaviour of `TRUNC` (and Oracle will implicitly cast the right-hand side of the comparison to a string); however, this is bad practice and will not always work ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6751a86e30ec44e15127f786142315c))

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` filter to restrict it to the days you want to total.

Also, don't use `TO_CHAR` in the conditional aggregation as:

1. You are not providing a format model so the behaviour is not well defined if the user running the query alters the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (which any user can do at any time within their own session; for example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6751a86e30ec44e15127f786142315c)).
2. It will prevent Oracle from using an index on the `eventtime` column (and you would need a function-based index instead).

Which would give you the query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '0' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day1,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '2' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day2,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '2' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day3,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day4,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '5' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day5,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '5' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '6' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day6,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN eventtime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '6' DAY
         AND  eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS Day7,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   table_name
WHERE  eventtime < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    eventtime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```